# How to freeze Excel settings: cell width/height, ... for only text input?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to give a group of people to fill Excel form. 
They need to use the same computer. 
In the meantime, the format often changes when people alter the cell width/height and font/...

I am thinking if you can only allow the user insert text into cells.

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it by [protecting sheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6):

> ### Step 1: Unlock any cells that needs to be editable
>
> In your Excel file, select the worksheet tab that you want to protect.
>
> Select the cells that others can edit.
>
> TIP: You can select multiple, non-contiguous cells by pressing
>   Ctrl+Left-Click.
>
> Right-click anywhere in the sheet and select Format Cells (or use
>   Ctrl+1, or Command+1 on the Mac), and then go to the Protection tab
>   and clear Locked.
>
> ### Step 2: Protect the worksheet
>
> Next, select the actions that users should be allowed to take on the
>   sheet, such as insert or delete columns or rows, edit objects, sort,
>   or use AutoFilter, to name a few. Additionally, you can also specify a
>   password to lock your worksheet. A password prevents other people from
>   removing the worksheet protection—it needs to be entered to unprotect
>   the sheet.
>
> Given below are the steps to protect your sheet.
>
> On the Review tab, click Protect Sheet.
>
> [image]
>
> In the Allow all users of this worksheet to list, select the elements
>   you want people to be able to change.
>
> [image]